# I get an error (RuntimeError: Event loop is closed) when i run my discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried integrating my code on a different webhost because my friend said it was faster. But when I did, I get an error that says `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. It was working perfectly fine before moving.

At first I thought it was because the .env file I made was wrong but I tried running the bot without loading the .env file `bot.run("token")` and still got the same error.

here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/home/discord_bot/main.py", line 1085, in <module>`
    bot.run(bot_token)
  File "/home/discord_bot/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 695, in run
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: loop.stop())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 89, in add_signal_handler
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

here's what in the .env file:

```
TOKEN = my_token
```

The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

bot_token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or("."))

...some server commands

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot is ready')
  print('------------')

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code!

Comment: @KlausD. code added. sorry it took awhile

Answer (score -1):

Try add this up to you token

```
bot.close()
```

Comment: Please explain where exactly to add this and how it is going to solve the problem!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).